# What is "marbles" in plural?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural, grammatical-number

> Taj Mahal is built using **marbles**

I heard that Material noun is always use in singular form

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "material nouns"?

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Material noun is name given to Material or substances, here marble is Material noun

Comment: That's not true. *Wood*, for example, can be used as an uncountable noun as well as a countable one: *I live near the woods*, *Wood used to be one of the primary sources of energy for mankind for thousands of years.*

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Woods I guess represents different type of wood or forest just like waters is use for water bodies .

Comment: Please wait at least 12 hours before accepting an answer. That way you'll get more answers to choose from (because otherwise people might not even look at the question when they see it's already been answered).

Comment: You're completely right that *marble*, like *metal*, for example, is an uncountable noun which denotes a material, and because it's an uncountable noun, it's followed by a verb in the singular. However, these nouns can also be used countably with the meaning "a type of *material* / *substance*". So ***a** metal* would be a type of metal. Similarly, if we have different types of **marbles**, we can refer to them as such. *Taj Mahal was built using marbles* probably means that Taj Mahal was built using different types of marbles.

Comment: From https://www.tajmahal.org.uk/taj-mahal-facts.html: "Different types of marbles used in construction of Taj Mahal were brought over from many different regions & countries: Rajasthan, Punjab, China, Tibet, Afghanistan, Srilanka [sic], & Arabia."

Comment: In the above comments I also used *Taj Mahal* anarthrously (without an article), which is ungrammatical. If you're ever gonna use that noun in English, you should probably learn that it's used with a definite article.

Comment: The example from tajmahal.org sounds funny to my (AmericanEnglish) ear. Because the toy ball meaning of "marbles" is so common, it still sounds like maybe the Taj Mahal was made from some combination of aggies, glassies, milkies, and shooters. I would pretty exclusively say "the Taj Mahal was built using different types of **marble**" if I wanted to avoid the impression that I meant [this kind of construction](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-M5rnzPWL3IQ/Ui-DxyDx7II/AAAAAAAAIpQ/uQNdDP_s0Vo/s1600/Frances.jpg)

Comment: @user491253 - Is this a sentence you found somewhere, or did you make it up?

Comment: @stangdon I found it here 
http://www.teachingbanyan.com/learn-english/grammar/parts-of-speech/noun/material-noun/

Comment: @user491253 - Thanks.  That page contains many, many grammatical errors.  I would not trust anything it says.  People here can advise you on the proper use of mass nouns.

Comment: @userr2684291: *Taj Mahal was built using marbles* probably means the speaker/writer isn't a native Anglophone, since we always refer to it as ***the** Taj Mahal*. But putting that aside, pluralising ***marbles*** there is effectively "domain-specific jargon", only likely to be used by specialists such as stonemasons and mineralogists (if at all; I'm not one of those, so I don't know if they actually *would* use.it). And in my opinion, ***different types of marbles*** is simply *invalid*, in all contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So you're saying a native speaker of English would always say *the Taj Mahal*? What about *Buckingham Palace*? If you've never heard it used in a sentence, how would you know exactly? I completely agree that *marbles* is probably domain-specific because most people would just say *types of marble*, and especially (coincidentally) because today *marbles* denotes the little balls used in a children's game. But just because it's uncommon doesn't mean it's ungrammatical. *Different types of marbles* should be grammatical, just like *different types of metals/clays/things* is.

Comment: @userr2684291: Google Books claims 18 written instances of [*He visited Taj Mahal*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+visited+Taj+Mahal%22), but I can only read the full context of one of them, and it's clearly written by a non-native speaker. And I've no reason to argue with the claimed 407 hits for [*He visited **the** Taj Mahal*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+visited+the+Taj+Mahal%22). The fact that nobody refers to ***the** Buckingham Palace* is irrelevant - it's about whether a usage is "idiomatic, established", not "grammatical".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Okay, I misunderstood you as implying that a native speaker would somehow know to include *the* before *Taj Mahal* even without having heard it before. And yes, *Taj Mahal* is always preceded by some kind of determining word like *the* (I'm not trying to argue against that).

Comment: @userr2684291: Well, if there's a long-term trend, we *do* tend to dispense with the article over time. *The Argentine* is long-gone, and *Ukraine* and *Lebanon* are increasingly becoming detached from their original "determiner".

Answer (score 1):

The Taj Mahal is built of marble, which is indeed in singular form. Marbles are small glass balls used as toys and in games.

Comment: The OED (2nd edition) contains this definition of *marble*: "A kind or variety of marble."

Comment: While correct, I don't think this address the underlying question.  The user isn't asking whether the Taj Mahal was built of *marbles*, but rather how to say it was built of various types of *marble*.

Answer (score 1):

By *material nouns*, you probably mean *mass nouns* which are nouns that are used to refer to things that generally cannot counted such as different substances like water, wood, milk etc. Well, that's not really true. Those things can be countable under certain circumstances. Specifically, when you are referring to different types or kinds of a particular substance. Wood, for example, can be used as a mass noun as well as a countable one. For instance:

> Several **woods** have been used to construct electric guitar bodies over the decades.
>
> **Wood** used to be one of the primary sources of energy for mankind for thousands of years.

When *marble* is used in its plural form, it means something slightly different from the type of stone used in architecture. Marbles are small balls children use play different games with. The reason they are called *marbles* is because they were originally made of marble:

[image: marbles]

But *marble* and *marbles* are not the same thing. That's why saying *a building made of marbles* does not make a lot of sense. Also, notice that you need a definite article in front of *Taj Mahal*. So, I would recommend rewriting your sentence like this:

> The Taj Mahal was built using **marble**.

Comment: I've never heard 'milks' used like that. I wouldn't say it's a normal usage, at least not anywhere I've ever lived. I would say 'types of milk' or 'brands of milk'. I would agree with you regarding 'woods'. In the case of 'waters', as in 'North American waters' it is used to refer to countable geographical water features, rather than types of water.

Comment: Alright. If you don't like the example with *milks*, I'll switch back to the one with *woods*.

Comment: *Waters* is plural and uncountable in the sense of *North American waters*; you cannot say (for example) *\*one international water, \*two international waters, \*three international waters*.  You can order *two waters* at a restaurant, though, so in that meaning it's plural and countable, though again it doesn't represent different kinds of water.  Likewise, *woods* in *I live near the woods* doesn't refer to different kinds of wood, but in *Several woods have been used to construct electric guitar bodies over the decades* it does.

Comment: Thank you. That's a better example. I'll use that in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin I meant no criticism. Just trying to help get the answer polished.

Comment: @dwilli as it happens, "milky marbles" are an opaque white colour (perhaps polished?) instead of being transparent glass. The colours are on the surface, instead of being inside the marble.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin  Actually, "a building made of marbles" makes perfect *English* sense, but very little *architectural* sense.  Still, it's possible to see the phrase in something like a whimsical children's song -- after all, Lennon and McCartney had no problems with *"tangerine trees and marmalade skies"*.

Comment: @snailboat So does it mean a lot of mass nouns can be pluralized to refer to different kinds of the same thing?